# javascript associative array with leading zero properties sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following JSON:

```
var somearr = {
"08":{val:blabla,val:blabla},
"09":{val:blabla,val:blabla},
"10":{val:blabla,val:blabla},
"11":{val:blabla,val:blabla},
...
"14":{val:blabla,val:blabla}
}
```

when doing

```
 for (  i in somearr) {   
   console.log(i);
 }
```

I got this sequence: `10, 11, ... 14, 08, 09`

How can the original sort order be achieved?

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of somearr you defined is a map(dict) not an array.
You can define an array by using [] e.g.

```
var somearr = [{val:blabla,val:blabla}, {val:blabla,val:blabla}, {val:blabla,val:blabla}];
for(var i in somearry) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

You'll get what you want

Comment: Don't use `for...in` for arrays. The iteration order is just as undefined as it for an object, and will also return methods added to `Array.prototype`.

Comment: @Tim-Down You're right. I wrote the scripts above just for demonstration. Some js frameworks would inject functions into Array's prototype. But I don't think it is a good js citizen should do :). The classical for var i & less than length loop is recommended anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Put the keys into an array, sort it, then iterate over it, and pull from the object.

Using Underscore.js:

```
var keys = _.keys(somearr).sort();
_.each(keys, function(key) {
  var value = somearr[key];
  console.log(value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The iteration order of properties using `for...in` is specified as being implementation-specific, and browsers do vary. Therefore if you need a particular order, you must use an array, which you can then sort and iterate over using a `for` loop. Here's how you can do it:

```
var keys = [];
for (var name in somearr) {
    if (somearr.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        keys.push(name);
    }
}

keys.sort();

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
    console.log(keys[i] + "=>" + somearr[keys[i]]);
}
```